# Should my Django site's main page be an app?

Tags: django

I have finished reading the Django official tutorial which teaches how to create a simple polls app, which is the way they chose to teach beginners the Django basics.
My question is, now that I know how to make a simple app and want to create my own website (using Django), should the main (front) page of my website, be an app as well? If so, how do people usually call it and configure it? I mean, it should do nothing but render a html template, so why make it so complicated? If not, where do I put all the static files and how do I reference them? I am a bit confused and could use your help. Maybe I misunderstood Django's main use?

Comment: Usually I create a `core` (or named similarly) app that has all of the extra bits and pieces like utility functions, context processors, middleware etc. This is a good place to put the index page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your templates and static files in the root project folder where your `manage.py` file lives. In the root folder create the following folders:

- `templates` (for HTML)
- `static` (for CSS, JS and images)

In your `settings.py` file, make these variables look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        ...
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**Note:** `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable is initially not present in the `settings.py` file, but you can add that by your own. Django, by default, finds static files in the `static` directory of each app. If you want Django to read the `static` directory you created in the project root, you need to add this variable. Django official documentation reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

To render these templates you can create `views.py` in the directory where your `settings.py` file lives and add the route in `urls.py` in the same folder.

This is one of the several ways to achieve what you want. Hope you won't need to plug these templates (eg, your home page) to or say use these templates in any other project, otherwise do as [Timmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396300/timmy-omahony) suggested in the comment on your post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping you could also mention what STATICFILES_DIRS does, because I didn't originally have it in my settings.py.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a note which explains why we added this variable.

Answer (score 11):

I usually start with 3 apps (call them whatever you want):

- **layout**  - basic layout: some common static files and a basic-template (other templates extend this one, main purpose is to
  include a common html `<head>` ). Also contains the home-page and some other simple pages.
- **config**  - contains the project settings / configuration, and the main `urls.py` (and in my case also wsgi.py)
- **myapp** - the actual app I want to create.

This nicely separates functionalities. Often I can just re-use the base app for other projects.

```
   $ ./manage.py startproject config
   $ ./manage.py startapp layout
   $ ./manage.py startapp myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render just one page then you can do something like this (from Django documentation) inside global `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path("home/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html")),
]
```

And then you make your `home.html` in root project `tempalates` to which you point from your `settings.py` and that should be it. No need for separate app....